# UNC Share Vs. Admin UNC Share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

So, I have a weird issue. I have a file on a network share that is updated every second.

When I access the file via unc share `\\server1\updatedfile\text.txt` the file is always stale. When I access via admin share `\\server1\c$\files\updatedfile\text.txt` the updates are always visible.

I'm stumped. Does anyone have any ideas as to why?

Server is Windows 2008 R2

Comment: the c$ path doesn't necessarily have to point to the same directory as the \\server\updatedfile\.  you can name the share anything you want.

Comment: thank tony.. example 1 is the share path.. example 2 is the location of the share if you drive to it manually via directory structure..

Comment: I'm just saying that \\server\c$\mud does not HAVE to equal \\server\mud \\server\mud it could equal c:\mud\water with the directory water being shared out as mud.

Comment: How is the file updated?  Is it open for write, or overwritten by a copy?

Comment: It's a memory map file.  Sync is used to write to disk

Comment: also is it a single file thats being updated, if so I'm not even sure how you are getting 1 second resolution on updates.

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest I did a quick search on SMB caching and found that there is such a thing as a client redirector cache. This caches info about files and their data to reduce network traffic. I wonder if this is the problem you are seeing, but this cache is in some way not applicable to the administrative shares.

Could it be worth setting the registry keys mentioned in the link below and seeing if your problem goes away?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200(v=ws.10).aspx

Sorry, I know this is a speculative answer, but it thought I'd give it a shot anyway.

Comment: doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the offline settings of the stale share.

Comment: offline settings are disabled

Comment: For completeness, can you submit the output of NET SHARE <SHARE_NAME>  ?

Comment: not using mapped drive.. calling via UNC..

Comment: This would still list open shares.

Comment: it does.. but this share is not one of them